# Pagination is not working properly in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, paging

My list is in Sharepoint Online. I want to do pagination of list data in my custom page.

**1st page code link:**

```
 https://xxx/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('abc')/items?&$top=5
```

**2nd page code link:**

```
   https://xxx/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('abc')/items?%24skiptoken=Paged%3dTRUE%26p_ID%3d8&$top=5
```

Above code is working fine because there is not order by in above code but when I add order by code it will not work as required.
**1st page code link:**

```
https://xxx/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('abc')/items?&$top=5&$orderby=Last_x0020_Modified%20desc
```

**2nd page code link:**

```
https://xxx/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('abc')/items?%24skiptoken=Paged%3dTRUE%26p_ID%3d177&amp;=&$top=5&$orderby=Last_x0020_Modified%20desc
```

Both the calls return same value because pagination works in greater id which is passed as "p_ID=177". Is there any alternative to do the pagination in sharepoint with order by clause in rest call?